# How to remove the border in the word, that was added when loading the template?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I added a template of .dot extension and after that border is coming in Blank word document automatically by default.
[image]

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should add a link in your question here to the new question here to help others. What you are seeing is a `Text Boundary`. http://addbalance.com/word/textBoundaries.htm

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon, this really helped me. Was searching the internet from about an hour, but never got such an accurate solution. Thank You!